# Different default page in MVC if authenticated

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirect, routes, forms-authentication

This might be a very simple question, but I have a hard time to understand the MVC routing.

Scenario: The user enters my site by entering www.mydomain.com in his browser. I would like to redirect to different default pages depending on if the user is authenticated or not.

My current authentication approach: In Application_PostAuthenticateRequest I check for a FormsAuthentication cookie. If found I parse user principal from cookie.

Where and how should I configure the redirect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure what the second part of your question really is supposed to mean, however, the main part of your question should be pretty straightforward.  This has nothing to do with "routing", just what you want to happen if someone comes to your index (root) page of your site.

Let's say this is your controller/action

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult AuthenticatedIndex()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Contact()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

        return View();
    }        
}
```

To test if someone is authenticated in a controller/action, you can use this line of code:

```
User.Identity.IsAuthenticated
```

which returns true/false depending on if the user is authenticated.  Next, we need to send the user somewhere else if they are authenticated.  That is done by using the following:

```
RedirectToAction("actionName", "controllerName");
```

So, if we tie all of this together, we can now update our `Index()` method and send the user somewhere else if they are authenticated.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    if(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated){
         //send them to the AuthenticatedIndex page instead of the index page
         return RedirectToAction("AuthenticatedIndex", "Home");
    }
    return View();
}
```

The only caveat I see here is that a logged in user will **Never** be able to get to the Index method, which may be what you want.

Comment: Thanks Tommy for your suggestion! I do want the "Index" page to be accessible for authenticated users as well. But following your idea I will rename the Index page to something else, then let the Index method have two Redirects depending on IsAuthenticated check. This way specific urls will always work and default will redirect the way I want. An external idea is always helpful to get you going :)